# Display API response as marker on HERE map - Flutter Mobile App

Tags: flutter, dart, here-api

I am calling an API from a Flutter project and it is successfully returning the Json.

I am able to display the information as text on an emulator fine. The response is returning the data fine.

However, I want to extract the Lat/Lon from the call and implement it into a function to display markers on a HERE SDK map.

The Marker works fine with manually entered coordinates, I am trying to take the API response and utilise it to display the multiple markers returned in the call.

Below is the section of code on the map marker dart file I have been trying to make the changes.

```
GeoCoordinates CoordinatesManager() {
    GeoCoordinates centerGeoCoordinates = _hereMapController.viewToGeoCoordinates(
        Point2D(_hereMapController.viewportSize.width / 2, _hereMapController.viewportSize.height / 2));
    if (centerGeoCoordinates == null) {
      throw Exception("GeoCoordinates are null");
    }
    double lat = centerGeoCoordinates.latitude;
    double lon = centerGeoCoordinates.longitude;
    
    
    return GeoCoordinates(51.482518, -0.612003);
  } 
  
}
```

`GeoCoordinates CoordinatesManager`
Links to a void in my Main.dart that displays the data on the map, calling
`void _anchoredMapMarkersButtonClicked()`
The API call is made from my API Manager with the following header

```
  Future<Stations> getStations() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var stations;
```

Comment: Your CoordinatesManager() function always returns the same hardcoded coordinates. Note that the map is already centered. If you just want to get the centered coordinate of the map view, you can just ask for the map view's camera current target location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to add a map marker to the map:

```
  void _addCircleMapMarker(GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates, String imageName) {
    // For this app, we only add images of size 60x60 pixels.
    int imageWidth = 60;
    int imageHeight = 60;
    // Note that you can optionally optimize by reusing the mapImage instance for other MapMarker instance.
    MapImage mapImage = MapImage.withFilePathAndWidthAndHeight(imageName, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    MapMarker mapMarker = MapMarker(geoCoordinates, mapImage);
    _hereMapController.mapScene.addMapMarker(mapMarker);
  }
```

It's adapted from the official [GitHub](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/5be0a315e854ba55aca92983203612ccf8eaa694/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/routing_hybrid_app/lib/RoutingExample.dart#L222) examples.